# Passing arguments in QueryString to a WebForm

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have following query method:

```
jxr['tafsir'] = jQuery.ajax({
                                url: url_interface + '/FetchData2',
                                type: "POST",
                                data: "{'currTarjama':'" + currTarjama + "', 'b_s':'" + b_s + "', 'b_a':'" + b_a + "', 'e_s':'" + e_s + "', 'e_a':'" + e_a + "'}",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    tarajem[currTarjama][currMosshaf][page] = data.d.tafsir;
                                    setTranslation(page);
                                    //alert(data.d);
                                },
                                error: function (data) {
                                    alert(data.d);
                                }
                            });
```

And following WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static object FetchData2(string currTarjama, int b_s, int b_a, int e_s, int e_a)
{
   return object = "test";
}
```

Above thing works fine.

My question is how to do it by passing arguments in a QueryString. I have following so far, it runs in Page_Load method but data.d always returns undefined.

```
jxr['tafsir'] = jQuery.ajax({
                                url: url_interface + '/QSData.aspx?currTarjama='+currTarjama+'&b_s='+b_s,
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    tarajem[currTarjama][currMosshaf][page] = data.d.tafsir;
                                    setTranslation(page);
                                    //alert(data.d);
                                },
                                error: function (data) {
                                    alert(data.d);
                                }
                            });
```

**QSData.aspx**

```
public object Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string jsonData = @"{'tafsir': {'1_1': {'text': 'Line 1'}, '1_2': {'text': 'Line 2'}}}";

            JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return (Dictionary<string, object>)jSerializer.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestions? Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I get following response in error: function (data) {}:

```
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
responseText: 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="QSTest.aspx?id=1" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZFdZL+JXL/hhgU0FybOa9M9LRjwzbDpthaDNCAwmpg/0" />
</div>

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure you are passing  url: url_interface + '/QSData.aspx?currTarjama='+currTarjama+'&b_s='+b_s ?

Comment: Thanks I was missing url. I have updated the question, any suggestion?

Comment: What happens if you make a WebMethod in QSData.aspx and change your URL in the AJAX call to call that method (eg. QSData.aspx/TestMethod)?    I'm curious if that returns the JSON in the way you want, rather than having the Page_Load method do it.

Comment: @mppowe: I tried it using WebMethod. It works and returns desired data. I need to do it using querystring.

Comment: @mrd What I meant was using the WebMethod but still supplying a query string, then in the WebMethod check the querystring Property (rather than having it as a passed variable to the method).  What I'm wondering is if the Page_Load can be used in the way you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to pass all the parameter for the method ;

```
  1 string and 4 int
```

are you doing so for query string ?

Your code shows that you are only passing 1 string and 1 int parameter in query string.

Comment: Yes, there are two arguments. Please see the updated question.